# Jenkins - skipped due to earlier failure(s)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set up a CI/CD, but at every step of my pipeline I get the following error message: skipped due to earlier failure(s)

//OUTPUT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh8Yi.png)

// JENKINSFILE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r2VC.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a timeout of 30 seconds set, if any stage takes longer than 30 seconds this is deemed to be a failure and the remaining stages will not be executed.

Your choices are

1. Remove the 3 second timeout, you can always apply this to a specific stage if you want to.
2. Determine whether the remainder of the stages can be executed if the timeout expires and allow them to run.

My guess is option 1 is preferable.